# dynamicLink giving nil in openUrl

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dynamic-linking

I am enabling the dynamic link for my application. I have added a URL prefix and creating a dynamic link with code.

Clicking on that link, preview is opening if app is not installed. But once the app is installed I am not able to get the link from openUrl method.

Can you one faced this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it.

I am not getting the link back on reinstall because I missed adding **FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains** array in info.plist file.

And make sure to pass scheme before configure firebase obj. If your scheme is your budbleID then no need to assign this.

```
FirebaseOptions.defaultOptions()?.deepLinkURLScheme = "your_scheme"
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Thank you.